# Problems looking for a specific sans-serif typeface

Tags: typefaces

I've had a peek at your question guidelines, it *looks* like my question is [on-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I really have no idea how to even research this problem, as my butchery of typography terminology will now demonstrate:

I'm looking for a fat, stubby sans serif typeface.  This is roughly the shape of, for example, my desired letter **'b'**:

[image: b]

I just screencapped an existing **'b'**, drew on it, and blew it up in MS paint, so it looks pretty terrible.  But it has aspects I'm looking for:

- a short, wide ascender (though this one is pretty extreme):

  [image]
- a circular count and bowl:

  [image]
- a wider ascender than stem:

  [image]

I'm pretty new to type, so I don't even know how to *look* for a typeface like this.  So far, scrolling through sites like [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) is overwhelming, and search queries like "*fat stubby sans serif*" are (unsurprisingly) not very helpful.  **How can I find a typeface like this?**  It'd be wonderful if someone could link me a specific font, but more valuable is help with the process of finding a typeface with criteria like mine.

I don't even know if such a search is even feasible - do people with these problems need to hire a designer for typeface design?  As far as I know, that's an extremely nontrivial task!

Comment: it's evocative of Bahaus, but the thicker ascender is unique. Where did you screen cap the b from? Were there other letters? Was it part of a logo (if so, it may never have been a actual font in the first place)?

Comment: It is indeed part of a logo - I don't think it was ever a font.  The worst part is that there are no more letters!   The problem I'm having is filling out the rest of the logo around the letter 'b'.

Comment: If the problem is too vague or open-ended, let me know and I'm happy to close the question.

Comment: Well, I think the answer to 'is this is a font' is likely "no, it's not" as odds are it was drawn that way for that particular logo. As for how to find fonts like this, http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ is a common place to start. Other than that, though, it helps to just have experience to know what to search for on font sites. Asking here is a good place as well--just as you have done.

Comment: DA01 is most likely correct that this character is actually not from a font but actually a custom drawn logotype. Even with today's technology, there is no easy way of reverse-searching a font. The process truly does consist of sitting at a computer and scrolling through samples on foundry sites. Can you find out who created this character? Perhaps they created a set of matching glyphs but it isn't on the web. Building a font from scratch isn't too difficult for someone with vector-drawing experience, but custom fonts are not cheap.

Comment: I just uploaded your sample to [MyFonts "What The Font?"](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but it didn't yield perfect results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some search terms you can use are Bauhaus, like DA01 mentioned, or geometric. However to find very specific characteristics, those terms will only take you so far.

You can upload a sample to [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), [The Font Matcherator](http://www.fontspring.com/matcherator) or try [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/).

You can browse related categories at [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=103)or [Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?filter%5Bsettings%5D%5B0%5D=show_more_tags&filter%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D=geometric&q%5Bterm%5D=geometric&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y)

If you don't find an exact match you have 3 options:

1. Use the closest font even if it's not an exact match
2. Draw/redraw/trace the characters you need
3. Find a type designer- and a big budget! ;)

Comment: Great response.  Geometric sans serif is a surprisingly powerful search term.  Option 1 is the most likely.  Thanks!

Comment: With the sites you linked and the search term "geometric" I was able to find several examples that worked.  I found [this article](http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-1/type-anatomy/type-classifications) where I can learn other words like "geometric".  Can you suggest any other/better resources?